# How can I group 4/5 of row mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I have data queried from table appears 1 day,2 days,3 days,4days....

I want to display them like 1-4 days, 5-8 days, 9-15days

Table Cruises:

```
id, length(days)
1 | 1
2 | 4
3 | 5
5 | 1
6 | 3
7 | 2
```

Currently I'm able to display it like:

[image]

I want it display like:

[image]

```
SELECT cruises.length, COUNT(cruises.id) as count FROM cruises GROUP BY cruises.length Having count > 0 ORDER BY cruises.length
```

This is the query I made so far

Comment: you write code. That's your job. We just (maybe) try help fix whatever you do end up writing.

Comment: at least show us whats the data structure of the table you're going to query...

Comment: If you already know the number of days, loop over the resulting rows and put the data into an array where the key is the group you want it to fall into.

Comment: `SELECT cruises.length, COUNT(cruises.id) as count FROM cruises GROUP BY cruises.length Having count > 0 ORDER BY cruises.length`

This is the query I made so far

Answer (score 0):

Im using another CASE to make another column, dont know if its the right way to do that.

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN "Upto 4 Nights"
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN "5-7 Nights" 
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 8 AND 14 THEN "8-14 Nights" 
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 15 AND 21 THEN "15-21 Nights" 
ELSE "Longer than 21 Nights" END AS cruise_length,
CASE 
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN 1
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN 2
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 8 AND 14 THEN 3
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 15 AND 21 THEN 4
ELSE 5 END AS cruise_length_id, 
COUNT(cruises.id) FROM cruises
GROUP BY cruise_length
ORDER BY cruise_length_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with ranges on the fly and join it with your table:

```
select r.from_length, r.to_length, count(*) as cruises
from (
  select 1 from_length ,4 as to_length
  union all select 5, 7
  union all select 8, 14
  union all select 15, 21
  union all select 21, null
) r -- range
join cruises c
  on c.length between r.from_length and coalesce(r.to_length, 10000000)
group by r.from_length, r.to_length
order by r.from_length
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40d81/2

In PHP you create the output while looping the rows:

```
if ($row['from_length'] == 1) {
    $label = 'Up to ' . $row['to_length'];
} elseif ($row['to_length'] === null) {
    $label = 'Longer than ' . $row['from_length'];
} else {
    $label = $row['from_length'] . ' - ' . $row['to_length'];
}
$label .= " Nights ({$row['cruises']})";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN "Upto 4 Nights"
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 5 AND 7 THEN "5-7 Nights" 
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 8 AND 14 THEN "8-14 Nights" 
WHEN cruises.length BETWEEN 15 AND 21 THEN "15-21 Nights" 
ELSE "Longer than 21 Nights" END AS cruise_length, 
COUNT(cruises.id) FROM cruises
GROUP BY cruise_length
```

I Ended up with this query as my preferred answer. Is there any possibility that I can order by 1-4 first, 5-7 second, 8-14 third onward?

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY MIN(cruises.length)`. `MAX()` will also work.